# Can Kibana issue a command similar to Splunks 'stats'?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm pretty well versed in Splunk, and am trying to pickup ELK.

I have an instance up and running, but I am struggling to build a mental map of ELK (likely due to my experiment with Splunk)

Is there a 'stats' like command in ELK,  where I could say something like

```
* | stats count by Variable
```

or even better

```
* | stats p50(Variable)
```

what would those commands be?  (or is my mental model incorrect?)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Splunk so I can't really tell what `stats` means.
But I guess you want to run here an elasticsearch aggregation which looks like:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "my_stats": {
      "stats": {
        "field": "variable"
      }
    },
    "my_p50": {
      "percentiles": {
        "field": "variable"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this is to run on elasticsearch. Kibana proposes some visualizations to do the same but using the frontend. There is no CLI in Kibana.
You can run the query I pasted in Kibana Console available at http://0.0.0.0:5601/app/kibana#/dev_tools/console if you are using elastic stack 5.0.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info - I use Splunk to rapidly search for logs, usually when I'm doing this I dont know exactly what I'm looking for and having a simple CLI is pretty nice

is there a recommended CLI for Elastic Search?  something that would compact the query to something more SQL like?

Comment: Nothing official. May be something from the community but I'd not use it and learn the DSL instead. Pretty easy with Kibana console. Even easier with Kibana UI (visualization/dashboards)